# Replace all commas outside parentheses AND quotes with REGEX or/and C#

Tags: c#, regex

I need to replace all commas outside parentheses and quotes

To replace only considering the parentheses I have the following REGEX
`,(?![^(]*\))`

I made the following REGEX that select the things inside parentheses and quotes in one group and the commas outside parentheses in another group, but I didn't find a simple way to replace the strings only for one group
`((?:\((?>[^()]|)*\)|'(?>[^']|)*'))|(,)`

Example:
What I want is to put this input

`ISNULL(d.Type, 0), d.Subject + ', ' + d.Name, d.Something,array_position(ARRAY['f', 'p', 'i', 'a']::varchar[], x_field), test`

and have this result

`ISNULL(d.Type, 0) DESC, d.Subject + ', ' + d.Name DESC, d.Something DESC,array_position(ARRAY['f', 'p', 'i', 'a']::varchar[], x_field) DESC, test`

Comment: Only ever one level of ( nesting? Example, `ISNULL(CAST(x AS Y), 0)`, if the first ) matches with the first ( you get `ISNULL(CAST(x AS Y), DESC), ...`

Comment: Only one level, don't need to check nested, if it's inside a () or '', ignore all things inside

Comment: In this case ```ISNULL(CAST(x AS Y), 0)``` don't change anything

Comment: Removing is easy with `Regex.Replace(text, @"(\([^()]*\)|'[^']*')|,", "$1")`

Comment: Are you looking for a C# regex ? Its trivial if you're ignoring paren nesting. Just slightly more is needed when nesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```cs
Regex.Replace(text, @"(\([^()]*\)|'[^']*')|\s*,", m => 
    m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Value : " DESC,")
```

*Details*:

- `(` - Group 1 start (the capturing group is necessary to restore the match later in the resulting string):

  - `\([^()]*\)` - a `(` char, then any zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)` char
- `|` - or

  - `'[^']*'` - `'`, zero or more chars other than `'`, and a `'` char
- `)` - end of the capturing group
- `|` - or
- `\s*,` - zero or more whitespaces and then a `,` char.

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/Nuvaqo):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var text = "ISNULL(d.Type, 0), d.Subject + ', ' + d.Name, d.Something,array_position(ARRAY['f', 'p', 'i', 'a']::varchar[], x_field), test";
        var pattern = @"(\([^()]*\)|'[^']*')|\s*,";
        var result = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, m => m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Value : " DESC,");
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ISNULL(d.Type, 0) DESC, d.Subject + ', ' + d.Name DESC, d.Something DESC,array_position(ARRAY['f', 'p', 'i', 'a']::varchar[], x_field) DESC, test
```

Comment: But of course, you have to check for the group or else you would get duplicate replacements right because of the alternation?

Comment: @Thefourthbird If you meant to ask why I am not using `"$1 DESC,"` as a replacement, yes, that is why there is a ternary operator in the lambda expression used as the replacement argument.

Comment: Yes exactly :-) ++

Answer (score 2):

I think I'd just have a simple state machine style interpretation..

```
bool inBra = false;
bool inQuo = false;

var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach(char c in str){
  if(c == '(')
    inBra = true;

  if(c == ')')
    inBra = false;

  if(c == '\'')
    inQuo = !inQuo;

  if(c == ',' && !inBra && !inQuo)
    sb.Append(" DESC,");
  else
    sb.Append(c);
}
```

You could handle nesting by making the bool an int that you ++ and --, and only DESC when it's 0

Comment: @Dmitry fixed, grazie

Answer (score 2):

I doubt if `Regex` is a good tool for the task: what if you have parentheses within quote?

```
abc + '(' + def, pqr + ')'
```

you want a simple, but *parser*. Let's implement it as a **F**inite **S**tate **M**achine:

```
private static string MyReplace(string value) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    return value;

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value.Length * 2);

  // if we are within quotation
  bool inQuot = false;
  // if we are within parenthesis (note, they can be nested)
  int parenthesis = 0;

  foreach (char c in value) {
    if (c == ',' && !inQuot && parenthesis == 0) 
      sb.Append(" DESC,");
    else
      sb.Append(c);

    // Possible states changing
    if (c == '\'')
      inQuot = !inQuot;
    if (!inQuot && c == '(')
      parenthesis += 1;
    if (!inQuot && c == ')')
      parenthesis -= 1;
  }

  return sb.ToString();
}
```